# Optimization based line fitting

Tags: matlab, optimization, mathematical-optimization, convex

I am using the following optimization script by which I am fitting the following curve y(t)=c_1+c_2 e^{-t} between two points y_1(t_1=0)=1 and y_2(t_2=10)=7

My question is, how can I solve the same optimization problem by adding the constraints y(t=5)>4?

```
clc;
clear;

tic

%The Data: Time and response data
t = [0 10]';
y = [1 7]';
%Look at the Data
subplot(2,1,1)
plot(t,y,'*','MarkerSize',10)
grid on
xlabel('Time')
ylabel('Response')
hold on
%Curve to Fit
E = [ones(size(t)) exp(-t)]
%Solving constrained linear least squares problem
% cNew = lsqlin(E,y,[],[],[1 1],y(1),[],[],[],opt) % Solver-based approach
p = optimproblem;
c = optimvar('c',2);
p.ObjectiveSense = 'minimize';
p.Objective = sum((E*c-y).^2);
% constraint example: p.Constraints.intercept = c(1) + c(2) == 0.82
sol = solve(p);
cNew = sol.c;
tf = (0:0.1:10)';
Ef = [ones(size(tf)) exp(-tf)];
yhatc = Ef*cNew;
%plot the curve\
subplot(2,1,2)
plot(t,y,'*','MarkerSize',10)
grid on
xlabel('Time')
ylabel('Response')
hold on
plot(tf,yhatc)
title('y(t)=c_1 + c_2e^{-t}')

toc
```

Comment: This is confusing. You provide two(2) data points and a parametric curve in two(2) parameters. This is a direct fit problem, not an OLS regression then. Did you mean that the two points bound the range of interest (and presumably you have data that falls between the two)?

Comment: How about modifying the objective function as follows. `p.Objective = sum((E*c-y).^2)+ 1e2*(sum(c)-0.82).^2;` . Read about Lagrange multiplier for constrained optimizations.

Comment: @J.A.Ferrand Sorry there was a missed part in the question I just modified. What I'm aiming to do is to fit(optimize) a curve between two points at T0 and Tf such that in between T0 and Tf , certain constraints are composed (e.g. T0=0, Tf=10 and constraint is at T=4 y(t)~=3)

Comment: @Praveen Could you please take a look at the comment I just added above

Answer (score 0):

From MATLAB's [documentation](https://www.mathworks.com/help/optim/ug/optimproblem.html), you can add the constraint using

```
p.Constraints.cons1 = c(1) + c(2) * exp(-5) >= 4;
```

Also, note that the strict inequality `>` is not supported by the optimizer for numerical reasons. So if you still want the strict inequality, then add a tolerance such as

```
tol = 1e-10;
p.Constraints.cons1 = c(1) + c(2) * exp(-5) >= 4 + tol;
```

Then proceed by solving the optimization as you did in your code.

Comment: Thanks for your support. It works! I have a question, which is also related to this question. Kindly, I want to ask if you can help! Let's assume that after solving the optimization problem I provided, and thereby a y_i(t) curve got composed, I want to solve the optimization problem one more time for different two points in the space (other two points to be added and a new j curve to be fit). In this second time, how can I solve the opt problem by composing a constraint that yj[t]~=yi[t]. Meaning, at each time step t, there's no conflict between y of the first curve and y of the second @Amro

Comment: please let me know if you need more clarification

Comment: The fitted function `y_i(t_i)` is valid on the range `t_i`. So if you have `t_j` (e.g., [1, 2]) within the range `t_i` (e.g., [0, 4]), then `y_j[t_i] = y_j[t_j]` without any computation. However, if `t_j` is outside the range of `t_i`, then you solve the optimization problem by adding equality constraints `y_i(t_k)=y_j(t_k)` for every `t_k` in `t_j`. The `t_k` are discretizations of `t_j`. This optimization problem may be difficult to solve numerically though.

Comment: Thanks for your reply, let me clarify the constraint a bit more. As you mentioned let's assume y_i(t_i) is valid on the range t_i (e.g., [0, 10]), also, similarly to the code above start point y_i(0)=1, and goal point y_i(10)=7. Now, I want to compose other curve y_j(t_i) which is valid on the same time range t_j=t_i. The idea is that I want y_j(t_i) curve to start at the point  y_j(0)= 2 and ends at y_j(5)=5, with No conflict in the position at any time step between the two curves (for all t yj[t] is not equal to yi[t]) @Amro

Comment: I'd also add three hints what might simplify the problem: 1- I am okay with using different objective function (another function can be taken rather than `y(t)=c(1) + c(2) * exp(-t)`). 2- turning the problem to be in 2D or 3D to avoid the conflict between two curves at certain time step is also ok. 3- the speed is not fixed, in other words, it's ok that the second curve starts at `y_j(0)= 2` and ends at `y_j(15)=5`, with benefiting from the negative `y` values @Amro